# Removing non-ascii characters on utf-16 (Python)

Tags: python

i have some code i'm using to decrypt a string, the string is originally encrypted and coming from .net source code but i'm able to make it all work fine. yet, the string coming into python has some extra characters in it and it has to decode as utf-16

here is some code for the decryption portion. my original string that i encrypted was "test2" , which is what is within the text variable in my code below.

```
import Crypto.Cipher.AES
import base64, sys

password = base64.b64decode('PSCIQGfoZidjEuWtJAdn1JGYzKDonk9YblI0uv96O8s=') 
salt = base64.b64decode('ehjtnMiGhNhoxRuUzfBOXw==') 
aes = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(password, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CBC, salt)
text = base64.b64decode('TzQaUOYQYM/Nq9f/pY6yaw==')

print(aes.decrypt(text).decode('utf-16'))
text1 = aes.decrypt(text).decode('utf-16')
print(text1)
```

my issue is when i decrypt and print the result of text it is "test2ЄЄ" instead of the expected "test2"

if i save the same decrypt value into a variable it gets decoded incorrectly as "틊첃陋ភ滑毾穬ヸ"

my goal is i need to find a way to :

1. strip off the non ascii characters from the end of test2 value
2. be able to store that into a variable holding the correct string/text value

any help or suggestions appreciated? thanks

Comment: Python2 or 3?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *python 2*, you can use `str.decode`, like this:

```
string.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

The locale is `ascii`, and `ignore` specifies that anything that cannot be converted is to be dropped.

In *python 3*, you'll need to re-encode it first before decoding, since all `str` objects are decoded to your locale by default:

```
string.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()
```

Comment: awesome it fixed 1 of the 2 issues :).  i was able to do

print((aes.decrypt(text).decode('utf-16')).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())

and it got rid of the non-ascii chars. but if i save it to a variable it changed from saving it as Asain chars to the variable just containing empty string 

text1 = (aes.decrypt(text).decode('utf-16')).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()

Comment: @johnjohnson Something like this: `text1 = aes.decrypt(text).decode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Comment: ok so i tried

text1 = aes.decrypt(text).decode('ascii', 'ignore')

and the result is Knklz0  , instead of "test2"

Comment: @johnjohnson Are you on python 2 or 3? Maybe you need to convert to utf-16 first and then convert to ascii.

Comment: i am on Python 3

Comment: Okay, my bad... `text1 = aes.decrypt(text).decode('utf-16').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()`

Comment: hmm yeah text1 is just text1='' , it's blank.. if i do a print instead of storing in a var it shows up fine

Comment: assuming you meant for me to try and encapsulate like this...

text1 = str(aes.decrypt(text).decode('utf-16').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())

that still only places blank or '' into text1..

Comment: @johnjohnson Ah... can't think of a solution. Guess utf-16 is the culprit here.

Comment: ok thx, yeah coming from .net to python , all the uni code and utf formats etc.. is a little bit of a struggle for me. but i'm farther along than before so thx :). will keep trying to plug away on this last bit. i fig it was something with utf-16.

Comment: @johnjohnson Last shot... try utf-8 instead of 16.

Comment: i tried

print((aes.decrypt(text).decode('utf-8')).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

it fails on the print even with..

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @johnjohnson Okay... then I'm stumped. utf-16 is the way to go, but I just don't know how to get you over that last hurdle. x(

Comment: roger that. yeah i'm not that keen on utf formatting coming from .net... i'll check into it later. but thanks getting me over the other hurdles... it's just it works fine print to console but i need to store it in a var :) and it's just no worky LOL

Comment: @johnjohnson I find it odd that it prints but but doesn't go into a variable.

Comment: :) ok so this works fine and goes into the var

text1 = str(aes.decrypt(text), 'utf-16').encode('ascii', 'ignore')

but the var shows up a "b" type byte... i thought it would not since i used str

Comment: @johnjohnson Good to know! Decoding causes it to become blank again?

Comment: OK :) what a journey LOL. so this works perfectly now

text1 = str(aes.decrypt(text), 'utf-16').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8")